# UISwitch in CustomCell is not changing the value at specific indexpath

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiswitch, custom-cell

This is the type of screen I'm making: [image: screen 1]

So when the `UISwitch` state changes it should change the label to `ON` or `OFF`. In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I'm calling `[cell.mainSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];` and `switchChanged` is as follow:

```
-(void) switchChanged:(id)sender {
    UISwitch* cellNew = (UISwitch*)sender;

        if ([cellNew isOn]) {
            cell.funcStatus.text = [funcStatusArr objectAtIndex:0];
        } else {
            cell.funcStatus.text = [funcStatusArr objectAtIndex:1];
        }
}
```

Now the problem I'm facing is that it is not changing the `Label` at the specific cell butt all the switches are changing the Label of 4th(last) cell as shown in the figure below.
[image: problem]
 As you can see that the first label is off but it is changing the label of last row. Any ideas why it is happening or how to tell the functions that this `index.row` is sending the request.

Comment: Looks like you are referencing the last cell at `cell` and the application updates the label correctly, the issue is then with the way you set or don't set `cell` value.

Comment: u must create cell for current indexPath. in your case always changes only last cell.

Comment: @KonstantinKryzhanovsky can you show me an example please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So u must add `tag` property to all `UISwitch`. Fasters way its in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` call

```
 // code
 // its good work if u have only 1 section
 mySwitch.tag = indexPath.row.
 //code
```

Than fix u're code

```
-(void) switchChanged:(UISwitch*)switch {
    SettingsTableViewCell *selectedCell;
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;
    if(switch.tag == 0)
      // create selectedIndexPath with correctrly row and section
       selectedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:'YourRow'inSection:'Your section']
      // create cell
       selectedCell = [self.tableView cellForIndexPath:selectedIndexPath];
     } else if(switch.tag == 1) {
      // same logic;
     }

    // and replace text for selected cell
    if ([switch isOn]) {
        selectedCell.funcStatus.text = [funcStatusArr objectAtIndex:0];
    } else {
        selectedCell.funcStatus.text = [funcStatusArr objectAtIndex:1];
    }
}
```

it's must work.

Comment: You used `UITableViewCell *selectedCell` but I'm using a custom cell `SettingsTableViewCell *cell;` so rest is fine but when it comes to last pat I can't do `selectedCell.funcStatus.text` because it's in `cell.funcStatus.text`

Comment: so replace `UITableViewCell ` to `SettingsTableViewCell ` .

Answer (score 1):

You doing wrong thing.First you need to get cell at specific changed event.
follow this code.

```
-(void) switchChanged:(id)sender {



    UISwitch* switchBtn = (UISwitch*)sender;
    //self.tableView is UITableView's outlet named tableView
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    //First detect Tableview's Cell then do the stuff
    //CustomCellTableViewCell replace it with you custom cell class
    CustomCellTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([switchBtn isOn]) {
        cell.funcStatus.text = [funcStatusArr objectAtIndex:0];
    } else {
        cell.funcStatus.text = [funcStatusArr objectAtIndex:1];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];


}
```

Cheers.